# Python rowcount returning negative 1

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

Please can someone help i cant believe I am not getting this right. I am trying to count the number of rows that I have in a mysql db. The correct number is 7, however everytime I execute the following I get an answer of -1. The connection is established successfully.I am using python 3.4.4

```
import mysql.connector

config = {
'user': 'root', 
'password': '', 
'host': '127.0.0.1',
'database': 'test'
}  
cnx =mysql.connector.MySQLConnection(**config)

if cnx.is_connected():
   print('Connected to MySQL database')

cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM test")
numrows = int (cursor.rowcount)
print(numrows)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-rowcount.html):

> For nonbuffered cursors, the row count cannot be known before the rows have been fetched. In this case, the number of rows is -1 immediately after query execution and is incremented as rows are fetched.

Which means that, in order for `.rowcount` to work in this case,  you have to *fetch the results first*.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM test")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
numrows = int(cursor.rowcount)
```

Of course, you can also get the length of the `rows` list.